# How to use the via method in Geb for a form that has multiple redirects?

Tags: methods, geb

Attempting to **assert that the correct landing page is being displayed after user authentication**.

Noticed that *after* authentication, the application redirects to a couple of pages that I was able to create page methods for.

```
given  
to LegacyLoginPage
when: someoneLogsIn(testUsername, testPassword)
then:
via AuthenticationTargetPage
and:
via LoginRedirectPage
//Thread.sleep(5000)
then: at ReferenceLibraryPage
```

When the spec is ran utilizing the `via` method, the test fails the assert step.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `via()` when the redirects are initiated by the server. `via()` changes the url the browser points at which is not what you want in this case. You are most probably after the following:

```
when: 
someoneLogsIn(testUsername, testPassword)

then: 
waitFor { at ReferenceLibraryPage }
```